# Экспорт сайта в excel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, excel

на сайте находится несколько таблиц,в таблице одна колонка занимает изображение, данные в таблицу поступаю из бд через php, как мне экспортировать эту страницу в excel в формате .xlsx при условии что изображения тоже должны экспортироваться, перепробовал много различных как плагинов, остановился пока на этом:

```js
<script>
            $("#btnExport").click(
                function () {
                    tableToExcel('wear', 'price', 'name');

                });

            function getIEVersion() {
                var rv = -1;
                if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
                    var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
                    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                        rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
                }
                return rv;
            }

            function tableToExcel(table, sheetName, fileName) {
                var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
                if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // ie
                {
                    return fnExcelReport(table, fileName);
                }

                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
                    templateData = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
                    base64Conversion = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
                    formatExcelData = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

                $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();

                if (!table.nodeType)
                    table = document.getElementById(table)

                var ctx = { worksheet: sheetName || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

                var element = document.createElement('a');
                element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64Conversion(formatExcelData(templateData, ctx)));
                element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                element.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(element);
                element.click();
                document.body.removeChild(element);

                $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
            }


            function fnExcelReport(table, fileName) {

                var tab_text = "<table border='2px'>";
                var textRange;

                if (!table.nodeType)
                    table = document.getElementById(table)

                $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();
                tab_text = tab_text + table.innerHTML;

                tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
                tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", false, fileName + ".xlsx");
                $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
                return (sa);
            }
</script>
```

Но проблема в том, он экспортирует в .xls формате , а данный формат не открывает мобильный софт excel <<файл не поддерживается или же поврежден>>.
Если есть решение данному вопросу буду признателен за помощь.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: ("SaveAs", false, fileName + ".xlsx"); разве у вас сохранение стоит не на xlsx?

Comment: Этот плагин работает с изображениями? Да, стоит .xlsx но сохраняет в .xls